# Add the contents of an autonumber field in the lead object as a suffix to a custom field in the lead object

Tags: sales

I'd like to add the contents of an autonumber field in the lead object as a suffix to a custom field also in the lead object.

I have an autonumber field called Enquiry Number. S-{000000}
I also have a custom field called Lead Name. This is manually populated with: Company Name - Product - S-000000

We use a standard naming convention for Lead Name, which also maps to Opportunity Name in the Opportunity object.

I would like to add the autonumber (s-000000) to the end of the Lead name to complete it when saved.

Can you please assist me with the formula for this?

Comment: Can you share the existing formula for custom Lead Name field?

Comment: It sounds like it's not a formula at present, which would mean either you need to change its type to formula or write a trigger.

Comment: Correct, it's not currently a formula field, just a text field.  We've only now made a decision to add the Enquiry Number as a suffix.

Answer (score 1):

If Lead Name is populated manually and you're not proposing to change it to a formula field, you'll need to implement an `after insert`/`after update` trigger on Lead. Auto Number fields are not populated until after insert.

Your trigger can concatenate the auto number field onto the existing Lead Name field. If you do fire it on update (this depends on when your Lead Name field is being populated), make sure to use a guard (static variable) against trigger recursion, because you'll have to fire another DML to update the field. You'll also want to check whether the field already has the auto number suffix from an earlier update or insert event.

If the field contents is always composed of the same data elements in the same order and format, you could replace it with a formula field, and break out the data elements (if appropriate) into their own fields for your users to populate. Then your formula can simply append the auto number value, and you can (if desired) implement validation rules on the new user-populated fields.

Comment: It sounds like as we're in the Dev stage, it would make sense (and best practice) to change the field to a formula field...is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Workflow to update the field. As I have used workflow many times to implement this functionality.

With workflow you have feasibility to control the behavior or can change the format without much changes in code.

Or else you can go with the trigger but there you need to handle recursive while in WF you won't face these issue.

Comment: This field maps to a field in Opp object and there is a WF in place for that.  I assume this won't be affected.  Are you able to give an example of the WF please?

Comment: @user54012 I don't have one right now. But you can try as it won't take much time.